# How to have external spring boot config .properties file without having a corresponding default .properties file in the fat jar?

Tags: spring-boot

I want to have a token in "private.properties" and I want this .properties file to be provided only at run time, I don't want to have this file in my .jar

So I exclude it in my packaging :

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/private.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources> 
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I launch my executable jar like this :

```sh
$ java -Dspring.config.additional-location=file:./config/private.properties -jar target/mytool-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I get :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [private.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

If there is an empty "private.properties" not excluded from packaging, it works.

What would be the way to have only an external private.properties ?

UPDATE :

here is the way I declare the file location in PrivateProperties.java :

```java
@PropertySource("classpath:/private.properties")
```

Do I have to hard code private.properties location to make it work ?

Comment: I guess the answer is "use @PropertySource("file:./any_path/private.properties")" as a default so that Spring is not upset with the absence of the file in the classpath, then override the location if needed at runtime with "-Dspring.config.additional-location"

Comment: after some tests, it's the same problem with "file:", some default file has to exist. Even if you use "-Dspring.config.location" instead of "-Dspring.config.additional-location" spring expects to have a file in the location described in source